# How search for list's each element existence in file

Tags: tcl

How can I organize a cycle using TCL for searching list's each element existence in file or in another list, and if it doesn't exists there return unmatched element.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I don't understand what you're trying to do. Any examples?

Comment: I have 2 files: file1, file2. length of file1 < length of file2.I have to check if every element of file1 exists in file2. If not return unmatched element.

Comment: Okay that's much better! And what is one element? One line in the file? Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: I know you want to get your question answered right away, but please take time to learn how to ask a proper question: describe your question in detail; give sample input and expected output; show what you have done so far. See this help page for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Hai Vu for your suggestion, It is my first question in stackoverflow.com. I will try to describe it more detailed.

Comment: I have 2 files:
FIle1:
CL0001UP
AND89HB
...
GAF9OL
___________________
File2 
CN00IL
CD9JK
CL001UP
.....
GA9UI
GAF9OL

The script should check if all strings (lines) in file1 exists in file2 (file2>file1). If there is string  that is  absent in file2 (for ex. AND89HB)  then write it in a new file.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of things that you are checking for is significantly smaller than the number of lines/tokens in the file, it is probably best to use the power of associative arrays to do the check as this can be done with linear scans (associative arrays are *fast*).

```
proc checkForAllPresent {tokens tokenList} {
    foreach token $tokens {
        set t($token) "dummy value"
    }
    foreach token $tokenList {
        unset -nocomplain t($token)
    }
    # If the array is empty, all were found
    return [expr {[array size t] == 0}]
}
```

Then, all we need to do is a little standard stanza to get the lines/tokens from the file and run them through the checker. Assuming we're dealing with lines:

```
proc getFileLines {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f
    return [split $data "\n"]
}

set shortList [getFileLines file1.txt]
set longList [getFileLines file2.txt]
if {[checkForAllPresent $shortList $longList]} {
    puts "All were there"
} else {
    puts "Some were absent"
}
```

It's probably better to return the list of absent lines (with `return [array names t]`) instead of whether everything is absent (with the general check of “is everything there” being done with `llength`) as that gives more useful information. (With more work, you can produce even more information about what is present, but that's a bit more code and makes things less clear.)

(When searching, be aware that leading and trailing whitespace on lines matters. This is all exact matching here. Or use `string trim`.)

---

Working with words instead of lines is really just as easy. You just end up with slightly different code to extract the tokens from the read-in contents of the files.

```
    return [regexp -all -inline {\w+} $data]
```

Everything else is the same.